# Xamarin iOS UICollectionView centering after swiping

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

I need when user do swip on horizontal layout CollectionView, after finish swipe selected cell will set in center of view.

Answer (score 0):

Need do folowing:

```
    ctor ()
    {
        CollectionView.Delegate = null; //Optionally
        CollectionView.WillEndDragging += CollectionViewOnWillEndDragging;
    }

    private void CitiesCollectionViewOnWillEndDragging(object sender, WillEndDraggingEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        eventArgs.TargetContentOffset = AdjustTargetContentOffset(eventArgs.TargetContentOffset);
    }

    private CGPoint AdjustTargetContentOffset(CGPoint eventArgs)
    {
        var countScrolledCells = (nint)(eventArgs.X / _cellWidth);
        var offset = eventArgs.X % _cellWidth;

        if (offset > _cellWidth / 2)
        {
            countScrolledCells++;
        }


        return new CGPoint(_cellWidth * countScrolledCells, 0);

    }
```

or http://blog.karmadust.com/centered-paging-with-preview-cells-on-uicollectionview/